# How to make TreeMap work with Arrays as key?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, treemap

Similar question see: [How to make HashMap work with Arrays as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576009/how-to-make-hashmap-work-with-arrays-as-key)

But I need TreeMap like `((int key1, int key2) -> String)`, comparing `key1` then comparing `key2`.

My solution is:

```
    Map<int[], String> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.
            <int[]>comparingInt(key -> key[0]).thenComparingInt(key -> key[1]));
```

But when I need `((int key1, int key2, int key3) -> String`, I must write more.

Is there a way to generate the Comparator for arrays with arbitrary length?

Comment: Probably the best way would be to just write a `Comparator` that does exactly that. I doubt that could be reasonably and understandably done with lambdas. If you can do it with a lambda, go for it, but personally I'd just use regular Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Comparator with a loop should do the trick.  Something like this, if I understood your requirement correctly.  I should mention that it assumes that all keys are of the same length.

```
    Map<int[], String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
            if (o1[i] > o2[i]) {
                return 1;
            } else if (o1[i] < o2[i]) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: Be sure to check the lengths first. Only enter the loop if the lengths are equal. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: Good point - I noticed that as I posted it.  I updated the original answer to indicate the assumption.

Comment: @Obicere if you do this you break symmetry requirement. You should return `+1` in case first array is longer and `-1` otherwise (or opposite, depending of what you want).

Comment: @talex exactly. I'd personally do it the same way. Just `Integer.compareTo(o1.length, o2.length)`.

Answer (score 12):

Since java-9 this could be greatly simplified with :

```
 TreeMap<int[], String> map = new TreeMap<>(Arrays::compare);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a factory method, which creates a comparator comparing the lengths of the arrays and their values:

```
public static Comparator<int[]> intArrayComparator(){
    return ( left, right ) -> {
        int comparedLength = Integer.compare(left.length, right.length);
        if(comparedLength == 0){
            for( int i = 0; i < left.length; i++ ){
                int comparedValue = Integer.compare(left[i], right[i]);
                if(comparedValue != 0){
                    return comparedValue;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        } else {
            return comparedLength;
        }
    };
}
```

Which you could call like the following then:

```
Map<int[], String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(intArrayComparator());
```

Above comparator has following cases:

- Left is bigger than right: return `1`
- Left is smaller than right: return `-1`
- Item at index i in left array is bigger than the one from the right array: return `1`
- Item at index i in left array is smaller than the one from the right array: return `-1`
- Left is deep equal to right: return `0`;