# Search Hashmap with Integer[] as a key

Tags: java, hashmap

Let's say that I've got a `Hashmap` and I would like array of two `Integer`s to actually be the key of each value. I can't figure out how to get the correct value back. It should already be stored in the `Hashmap`

```
public class Mapky {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer[], String> mapka = new HashMap<>();
        mapka.put(new Integer[]{10,23}, "Hello");
        System.out.println(mapka.get(new Integer[]{10,23}));
    }
}
```

Also why does this

```
System.out.println(new Integer[]{10,23}.equals(new Integer[]{10,23}));
```

return `false`?

Comment: You can't. Arrays are only ever equal to themselves. Create a proper class with hashCode and equals(). or at the very least, use a List<Integer>. Avoid arrays in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a reference to the key.
If you create a `new Integer[]{10, 23}`, you will create **a different one** which has the same value but is not the key.
Do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer[], String> mapka = new HashMap<>();
    Integer[] key = new Integer[]{10, 23};
    mapka.put(key, "Hello");
    System.out.println(mapka.get(key));
}
```

Comment: I can't even answer because while I was typing someone marked this as duplicate. My answer is more generally applicable, and similar to [Genzer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15576366/1052284) on the 'duplicated' question.